# Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite screen turning off in protective case

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s, android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a new `Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite` with a pen. Also I have a protective book-like case ([Aceline Streak STR-008](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dns-shop.ru%2Fproduct%2F033f7391d2373332%2Fcehol-knizka-dla-samsung-galaxy-tab-s6-lite-2020-seryj%2F&psig=AOvVaw2iBbFw9LWYHXXikM0E7pgz&ust=1613676780755000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCODq-dXU8e4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)).
The device works fine, except one thing: when I open the case and fold it backwards (I mean flip the front cover backwards behind the back side of the device) - screen gets turned off. It doesn't happen if I just put the tablet onto something. Device doesn't reboot or has any kind of abnormalities with this. When I remove the front surface of the case and let it just hang down freely - the screen turns on.

What can be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Is the front cover containing a magnet?

Comment: @Robert quite possible.

Comment: I would assume that this magnet triggers a sensor that is designed to detect the original Samsung cover. If you flip the cover the magnet triggers the sensor and the tablet thinks that the original cover is closed.

Comment: @Robert what is interesting is that that cover consists of three connected surfaces and even if only one third of it gets pressed to the back side of a tablet then the screen gets switched off. I wonder, if there is a solution to control those sensors...

Comment: Looks like you have a [tag:smart-cover].

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, this is an irony I suppose. Cause it behaves quite dumb in my case.